# linq expression error:cant display column name

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I am using LinqPad 4(nutshell database) and I am trying to display the (Customer) Name which is a column in the Customer table.
How can i display the Name in this query because now I am getting an error: does not contain a definition for 'Name'?

```
   from p in Purchases 
join c in Customers on p.CustomerID equals c.ID
group p by p.Date.Year into SalesPerYear
select new {
customername= SalesPerYear.First().Name,
customerid= SalesPerYear.First().CustomerID,
totalsales= SalesPerYear.Sum(x=>x.Price)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

**I assume you have a Purchase table with (Price, CustomerID and Date) columns..**

```
from p in Purchases  
group p by p.Date.Year into SalesByYear 
select new { 
customerid = SalesByYear.First().CustomerID, 
year=SalesByYear.Key, 
TotalVal = SalesByYear.Sum(g => g.Price) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already grouped by CustomerID, therefore it is the grouping key. i.e. in your query, you should say: `customerid = SalesByYear.Key`. Not sure where the year comes from in your query.

Comment: yes it works thanks! i am joining with another table how can i display the name from the customer table?

Comment: If you have a foreign key reference between Customer and Purchase tables in your database, you should be able to navigate to Customer object from Purchase, as the foreign ke becomes a navigation property...something like SalesByYear.First().Customer.Name.